# Checkbox component not working. (MATERIAL UI, REACT-HOOK-FORM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using a material checkbox but it doesn't return true or false. This is my code:

```
 <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox defaultValue={data.hasPhone} defaultChecked={data.hasPhone} color="primary" {...register("hasPhone")}/>            
      }
      label="Do you have a phone"
    />

{hasPhone && (
              <Input
                {...register("phoneNumber")}
                id="phoneNumber"
                type="tel"
                label="Cellulare"
                name="phoneNumber"
              />
            )}
```

When the checkbox is true, we have a condition, "hasPhone" that open another input field.
If i use a my checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" placeholder="Developer" {...register("hasPhone")} />
```

in above case the condition working correctly.

Can you help me please? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is working for your "hasPhone" `<input />` is that it is a native form element in contrast to the Material UI `<Checkbox />` component, which is an external controlled input.

So for native form elements you can use `register`, but for external controlled components you have to use RHF's `<Controller />` component. Check this [section](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) in documentation for more infos.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]